# Java - get real filename of symlink on remote HTTP Server

Tags: java, http, symlink

I am working within Java, and downloading files from a HTTP Server. Now we are working with symlinks here, so we do not need to change the http link - it is always pointing to "last-uploaded.zip" which is linked to the last uploaded zip file, as an example "package43.zip".

Do I have the chance to get the original filename within java? So the link is pointing to "last-uploaded.zip" but if it is downloaded I want to rename it to "package$version.zip".

Regards,
Marco

Comment: Not an option. You just can't do that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. The whole symlink concept doesn't transfer over HTTP, so when you make a HTTP GET for `last-uploaded.zip` you don't know if it's a file, a symlink or just an endpoint that returns bytes.

The simplest solution is probably opening the zip and searching for the version number from inside there somewhere.